# How to prove that $2^{n+3} = O(2^n)$?

Tags: asymptotics

I am a little confused on how to prove/disprove Big O.

For the problem, $2^{n+3}= O(2^n)$, I did the following:

$$2^{n+3} \leq K \times 2^n$$

Set $K = 1$

$$2^{n+3} \leq 2^n$$

Test for large values of n (so I plugged in n = 100)

$2^{103} \leq 2^{100}$  --- which is false therefore Big O is disproven

Is this process correct?

Comment: No, it's not correct. $2^{n+3}$ is $O(2^n)$ if there exists a constant $c$ such that $2^{n+3}\le c2^n$ for all large enough $n$. All you have shown is that $c\neq 1$; you need $c=8$.

Comment: Thanks.  That makes sense.  Is there a method to prove them without picking values for 'c' and 'n' or is that the only way?

Comment: "which is false therefore Big O is disproven" -- *wrong*. **Wrong!** Landau notation says something about behaviour *in the limit*; you can not disprove such a relation with a finite sample!

Comment: @Raphael, the "it fails for this single case, therefore it is false" is sadly widespread. Here it even adds a parameter $K$, arbitrarily set to 1...

Comment: @vonbrand Sad, but probably won't change as long as we [keep telling](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/20272/98) people to just plot it without warning.

Answer (score 1):

Just, replace the constant $K = 2^3$, and you have to use this constant for your proof.

$$ 2^{n+3}  = K\times 2^n$$

So, $O(2^{n+3})  = O(2^n)$.

Comment: This says nothing that isn't already contained in my comment to the question.

Comment: @DavidRicherby So why did you not post an answer?

Comment: Why we have to use constant K=8? I am not getting it